# Do visits still count against announcer/booster/publicist badges on the original site when a question is migrated?

Tags: support, migration, publicity-badges

I just posted a link to one of my [favorite SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72394/218589) on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/fje8x/what_should_a_developer_know_before_building_a/). After a few hours the question was migrated to programmers. So will my link on reddit keep counting against the badges (announcer/booster/publicist) on SO or against the same badges on programmers?

**EDIT:**

There must be some dev out there that can answer this question.

I expect one of the following answers:

1. No, by design, after the question is migrated the link no longer counts against the badges.
2. Yes, it still counts, and your link only received X (X<300) hits within the 4 day period.
3. Oooops, we did not think of that.

It should just be a matter of checking the source code, right?

Comment: I don't know if it will still contribute towards Stack Overflow, but on Programmers I imagine, were it to count, that it would be contributing towards the publicist badges of a non-existent user 218589.

Comment: @Grace, hmm ok, is that the desirable behavior?

Comment: I do not know. That's simply what I expect based on the fact that publicist links are based on userid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not count. If you want it to count, you need to re-share from the final site the question ended up on.

Comment: Ok Jeff. Thanks for your answer. I think this specific question got migrated **because** when I shared the link, the question's activity rose noticeably. I don't think moderators should migrate 2 year old questions in cases such as this.

Answer (score 0):

The shared link is still `stackoverflow.com/q/[question id]/[user id]` so it will still go through SO.

I would expect it would still count towards the badge on SO.

To get the badge on Programmers' (say) you'd have to share the link of the form `programmers.stackexchange.com/q/[question id]/[user id]`

Comment: Yes, I know that the shared link still points at SO, however I suspect that it does no longer count against the badges. I'm pretty sure I would have been granted at least the "booster" badge at this point, but I haven't.